# Неизвестная кодировка текста

Tags: кодировка

Получаю файл в формате **.gz**. Внутри архива находится файл с таким содержимым (фрагмент):

> [{"i":"11549466","t":"1616446800","ts":"1616533200","n":"J5q6/7OMYhVoYZ18o/7zWVLDRFcqEsVJJmVcL6EvuezK+1/AVqK/ag=="},{"i":"11668345","t":"1616459100","ts":"1616468400","n":"Qz0mbcP5dDc/DTakFg9Kn38JUpwZVnaxYxvU/2J7+3kGF5p3jtFexUEIkFICi99LEHjrac9Ynr4itMD02EU=","d":

Похоже на **Base64**, но ни один онлайн-конвертер не может преобразовать текст в кавычках в читабельный текст.

**Вопрос**: что это может быть за кодировка?

Comment: *Получаю файл в формате .gz.* Откуда? с какой целью? что в нём ДОЛЖНО быть? Есть ли пример файла и соответствующего ему расшифрованного значения?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что там должен быть читабельный текст? base64 декодирует успешно, просто там не текст, а бинарные данные.

Comment: И это, кстати, логично, что там бинарные данные, зачем бы нужно было текст кодировать в base64.

Comment: Этот файл содержит данные о телепрограмме. Как я понимаю, цифры - это начало и конец передачи в unix-формате, а далее следует текст - название передачи, который и закодирован. Вот его то и нужно расшифровать. Декодированного файла у меня нет. Но здесь точно зашифрован текст.